# Delete API is not in sync with Enterprise Architect table

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am trying to delete an element from EA by using the below code

```
Elements.Delete(i)
```

By using the above mentioned code the Element is getting deleted from the Project browser but its not getting deleted from t_object table. Sometimes the object in the t_object is deleted but t_object_properties in not getting deleted.

How to delete the Element and its properties from Project as well as from t_object ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not assume that an API call will also be reflected directly in EA's tables, nor can you assume to see table updates to be visible in the API unless you restart EA. There can always be caches you don't see and which you can not influence.

However, I'll take a look to see if there's a way to solve the above.